# Does an .xml file have a character limit?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I'm looking to export .xml from a Greenplum database. Currently, we only support exporting into Excel 2003, which supports up to about 60,000 rows, which isn't enough.

My question is; does an .xml file have a character limit?

Thanks

Comment: XML is a free-test file format, so there is no character limit. Each tool has its own limits in terms of capabilities of XML files it can process. For Greenplum, you have to perform "transformation" before loading the data, i.e. transform XML into delimited data file, and here is where you might face limitations depending on the type of tool you use

Answer (score 0):

No, Excel is has plenty of limits though.